# Unit test AjaxRequest C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

```
[Test]
    public void DetailPromocodeStatusWithModel()
    {
        var sut = _testContext.Sut;
        _httpModelFactory.FakeHttpContext();
        var mockHttpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
        var mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
        mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(mockRequest);
        mockRequest.Stub(x => x.HttpMethod).Return("POST");
        var context = new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext,new RouteData(),sut);
        sut.ControllerContext = context;


        var viewResult = sut.Enquire(SampleEnquiryForm());

        Debug.Assert(viewResult != null, "view != null");
        Assert.NotNull(viewResult);
    }
```

*I am unit testing a class that has a particular IF statement that that requires my request to be a POST and isAjaxRequest to be true to get into a particular block. I have set up the POST part but I can't seem to set the headers to make it an AJAX request, without it failing. *

Comment: Can you add the code with if-statement block and that you tried to do so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unit-test you can mock isAjaxRequest() method to get into needed block. Personally, I use [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/docs) for such purposes, since it allows to mock static methods. Take a look:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestIsAjaxRequest()
{
    var fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance<HttpRequestBase>();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest(null)).WillReturn(true);

    Assert.IsTrue(AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest(fake));
}
```

Hope it'll be helpful.